# Python Waterfall Logic for Capacity Allocation based on Prioritization

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement a Python program to allocate capacity using a waterfall logic, considering the prioritization order of route types, parcel types, and warehouse types. I have three lists of prioritization: route type > parcel type > warehouse type. The goal is to fulfill the demand for each delivery station on a given date by utilizing the available capacities from the highest priority route down to the lower priority ones, while ensuring we meet the capacity needs for the highest parcel and warehouse types. I got error

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

for my function

````
import pandas as pd

def allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df):
    allocation = []
    demand_index = 0
    total_used_capacity = 0
    
    for _, row in route_capacity_df.iterrows():
        route = row['route_type']
        route_capacity = row['capacity']
        route_used_capacity = 0
        
        while route_used_capacity < route_capacity and demand_index<demand_df.shape[0]:
            route_used_capacity += demand_df.at[demand_index, 'demand']
            total_used_capacity += demand_df.at[demand_index, 'demand']
            allocation.append((route, demand_df.at[demand_index, 'parcel_type'], demand_df.at[demand_index, 'warehouse_type'],demand_df.at[demand_index, 'demand']))
            demand_index += 1
        
        if total_used_capacity > mechincal_capacity_df.at[0, 'capacity']:
            break
            
        if route_used_capacity == route_capacity:
            continue
        else:
            # we need to split value
            overflow = route_used_capacity - route_capacity
            last_added = allocation.pop()
            allocation.append((last_added[3] - overflow))
            
            # the overflow should be used in the next lists also
            demand_index -= 1
            demand_df.at[demand_index, 'demand'] = overflow

    return pd.DataFrame(allocation, columns=['route_type', 'parcel_type', 'warehouse_type'])

demand_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'warehouse_type': ['Type A', 'Type B'],
    'delivery_station': ['Station 1', 'Station 1'],
    'date': ['2023-07-23', '2023-07-23'],
    'parcel_type': ['Small', 'Medium'],
    'demand': [50, 30]
})

route_capacity_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'delivery_station': ['Station 1', 'Station 1'],
    'route_type': ['Express', 'Standard'],
    'date': ['2023-07-23', '2023-07-23'],
    'capacity': [100, 150]
})

mechincal_capacity_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'delivery_station': ['Station 1'],
    'date': ['2023-07-23'],
    'capacity': [120]
})

result = allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df)
print(result)
```

Error log:

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-58c3eb663ba2> in <module>
     56 })
     57 
---> 58 result = allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df)
     59 print(result)

<ipython-input-63-58c3eb663ba2> in allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df)
     32             demand_df.at[demand_index, 'demand'] = overflow
     33 
---> 34     return pd.DataFrame(allocation, columns=['route_type', 'parcel_type', 'warehouse_type'])
     35 
     36 # Example usage:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    472                     if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
    473                         columns = data[0]._fields
--> 474                     arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
    475                     columns = ensure_index(columns)
    476 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    459         return [], []  # columns if columns is not None else []
    460     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 461         return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
    462     elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
    463         return _list_of_dict_to_arrays(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    488 def _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=False, dtype=None):
    489     if len(data) > 0 and isinstance(data[0], tuple):
--> 490         content = list(lib.to_object_array_tuples(data).T)
    491     else:
    492         # list of lists

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array_tuples()

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
````

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the _full_ traceback that reported `int64` is not a container having a length.

Comment: updated error tag

Answer (score 1):

If you print out `allocation` before converting it into dataframe, you'll see that it is a list of 3 elements, looking like one row of the future dataframe:

```
def allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df):
    # ... your code ... #

    print(allocation)
    return pd.DataFrame(allocation, columns=['route_type', 'parcel_type', 'warehouse_type'])
```

Output:
`[('Express', 'Small', 'Type A', 50), 50, 150]`

pandas is trying to parse it as a list of rows and fails, because the first "row" is a tuple with a certain length, and while trying to compare the lengths of the other "rows" it turns out that they are just numbers and don't have any length.

Your can do this if you're supposed to have 1 row as a result (note brackets around `allocation`):

```
def allocation(demand_df, route_capacity_df, mechincal_capacity_df):
    # ... your code ... #

    return pd.DataFrame([allocation], columns=['route_type', 'parcel_type', 'warehouse_type'])
```

Then you'll get

```
                     route_type  parcel_type  warehouse_type
0  (Express, Small, Type A, 50)           50             150
```

If you are not supposed to get just one row, then there is a mistake with appends to `allocation`, I can't say right now without digging into the logic.